# CAD file Converter Service / Library

Tags: java, converters, cad

I need to convert Inventor (.ipt), NX (.prt), SolidEdge (.par), Pro/Engineer / PTC (.prt) and STEP file formats among themselves. (bi-directional)
Are there any reliable and robust libraries (preferable Java) or (web-)services which can cope with this task and do preserve vendor specific annotations or attributes beside geometric data.
Additionally it must be executable programmatically and standalone.

So far i have only found

- TransMagic (Camtex)
- Direct Translatorv (Elysium Global)

But both are not perfect matches.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: EWS does not support all the file formats you mentioned but it would worth a try: http://www.devdept.com/eyeshot/webservice

Comment: Thx Alberto, Looks like a nice ws aiming at what i am looking for but unfortunately does not support all target formats as you already mentioned!